# Algorithm(s) for automatic layout of nodes and connections

Tags: algorithm

I'm planning on building a subsystem of one of my projects for laying out a set of interlinked nodes optimally. The nodes would represent websites and website pages and the connections would represent links between pages. The user will add the first page to the diagram, then add additional pages that link back to the original page. Along the way, some pages will cross-link to other pages.

Where can I start researching algorithms to automatically select "clean" paths for connection lines, for automatically selecting the best place to position new nodes as they are added and for automatically laying out an entire diagram?

Comment: The research area is called "graph drawing".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the work done by the authors of [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/).  That website has links to some of the background reading you ought to tackls.